# Access the text within SVG object using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am new to d3js and am trying to get the text value from SVG element. Below is my code html and javascript:

**HTML Before d3.json load:**

```
    <div id="model_container" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 20%">

   </div>
  <span>
      <button onclick="getAllMapReactions();">ADD</button>
    </span>
```

**HTML After d3.json load:**

```
<div id="model_container" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 20%">
.
.
.
.
 <g id='reactions'>
     <g id='r0' class='reaction'>
       <g class='reaction-label-group' transform='translate(360,500)'>
         <text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO</text>
       <g id='r1' class='reaction'>
         <g class='reaction-label-group' transform='translate(365,500)'>
           <text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO2</text>
</div>
  <span>
  <button onclick="getAllMapReactions();">ADD</button>
</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
d3.json(document.getElementById("model").value, function(error, data) {
     if (error) console.warn(error);
     var options = {menu: 'all', canvas_size_and_loc: { x: '200', y: '200', width: '5000', height: '5000' }};
     var b = escher.Builder(null, data, null, d3.select('#model_container'), options);


     b.map.new_reaction_from_scratch('GAPD',{ x: 350, y: 315 }, 90);
     b.map.new_reaction_from_scratch('PGK',{ x: 950, y: 315 }, 90);
     b.map.select_all();
   });



function getAllMapReactions() {
var reactionsVar = [];
      reactionsVar = d3.selectAll(".reaction-label-group").each(function (d) { reactionsVar.push(d3.select(this).text())});
      console.log(reactionsVar);

     alert(reactionsVar);
}
```

From above, I would like to extract the "HELLO" or "HELLO2" from `<text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO</text>`, however I get a svg object.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with it? Otherwise it is tedious to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is `d3.textSelection`? I am not aware of any d3 property with that name. Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: @ccprog, apologies the code is `d3.select(this).text()`. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the the `<g>` element, not the `<text>`. Note the selector:

```
function getAllMapReactions() {
    var reactionsVar = [];
    d3.selectAll(".reaction-label-group text").each(function (d) {
        reactionsVar.push(d3.select(this).text())
    });
    console.log(reactionsVar);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the concise explanation, I appreciate that.  The `var reactionsVar = [];
  reactionsVar = d3.selectAll(".reaction-label-group").each(function (d) { reactionsVar.push(d3.select(this).text())});
  console.log(reactionsVar);
  alert(reactionsVar);` is executed within a function after the JSON data is loaded and with the add button is pushed. I have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Then the above should cover your question.

Comment: thanks again. However, when I do `alert(reactionsVar);`, I get `[object SVGTextElement]`.

Comment: You assigned `reactionsVar = d3.selectAll(...)` and thus wrote over the array. Compare last edit.